# Select intersection of many values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a bit of a SQL problem and need your help. I am querying an Oracle database from a workflow (application-specific term). I need to get the correct catgeory value from a table that looks like the below given a list of CRI_IDs.

```
    CAT             CRI_ID
    268_0_43_BR     506
    268_0_43_BR     507
    268_0_43_BR     508
    268_0_43_BR     509
    462_406_42_TR   508
    462_406_42_TR   509
```

It seems simple but the problem is that the same CRI_ID can have more than one CAT. So the basically I would have a variable ${CRI_IDs} which contains a list of CRI_IDs. Take this as an example:

- ${CRI_IDs}=506,507,**508,509** >> Expected CAT=268_0_43_BR
- ${CRI_IDs}=**508,509** >> Expected CAT=462_406_42_TR

This make any use of Join/Intersect/sub-query not possible since I would always get both categories back. Any idea what would be a suitable query in this case?

I already tried stuff like the below but it returns both categories.

```
    select cat from table where cri_id in (${CRI_IDs});
    select table.cat from table join (select ${CRI_IDs} from dual) tmp on table.cri_id=tmp.id;
```

BTW feel free to assume instead of the variable that I have another table (tmp for example) that contains the list of CR_IDs in one of its columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select cat
from t
group by cat
having sum(case when cri_id in (506, 507, 508, 509) then 1 else 0 end) = 4 and
       sum(case when cri_id not in (506, 507, 508, 509) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts how may rows meet each condition.  The first is looking for the `id`s you want for the `cat`.  The `= 4` specifies that all must be there, assuming that the table has no duplicates.  (Duplicates are easily handled but they slightly complicate the query.)

The second condition looks for `cri_id`s *not* in the list.  The `= 0` specifies that none are found.

Comment: Seems to work for me! One concern I have would be the performance ... do you think it would be a hit to performance if I do this potentially with hundreds of IDs?

Comment: @MostafaHelmy . . . The performance is pretty much based on the number of rows in the table -- and the effort for the aggregation.  Adding more ids will have little impact on the performance.